# How to translate ギアを収納

Tags: translation

Could you tell me how to translate ギアを収納? The whole sentence is 成田空港から離陸した直後のです。ギアを収納中みたいです。 I cannot think of a translation in English.

Comment: ギア in this sentence means ランディングギア http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_gear .

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of ambiguous but it is referring to the landing gear retracting into the plane.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about right after take-off of an airplane.

"The landing gear is (now) up."